# OpenGL 3.3 Projection Matrix Error

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I am trying the tutorial on OpenGL 3.3 as presented : http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/

It says a projection matrix can be created with GLM as :

```
glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(45.0, 4.0/3.0, .1, 100.0 );
```

However, as I try to compile my code, with it, I get the following error:

```
 error: conversion from ‘glm::detail::tmat4x4<double>’ to non-scalar type ‘glm::core::type::mat4 {aka glm::detail::tmat4x4<float>}’ requested
make: *** [src/main.o] Error 1
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing a double try passing float arguments instead.

```
glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, 4.0f/3.0f, .1f, 100.0f );
```

Comment: oooh, thanks....couldn't guess that could be the problem from the compiler error.

Comment: @mkuse: C++ templates are nasty little things. Personally I try to avoid them in my code where they don't make things a lot easier or better readable. They rock if you have to instanciate code for a number of type combinations / permutations. Explicit type instanciation is BTW, what you could have done as well: `glm::perspective<float>(…)`